# Path's d attribute is being removed after attrTween in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have an arc being created and then tweened with attrTween in d3.js. Inside the tween function, everything looks fine and when I use 'this', i'm seeing the path with all of its attributes properly including the 'd' path.

At some point however, the 'd' attribute is being removed from the path, and it's not rendering.

While debugging, a few times I saw the arc render properly and stay rendered after debugging was done, but I wasn't able to intercept what could be causing the issue.

I've omitted as much of the irrelevant stuff as I could think of.

```
leftInnerArc = group.selectAll("path.goalchart-left-inner")
        .data([data]);

    leftInnerArc.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "goalchart-left-inner")
        .attr("endAngle", function (d) {
            return goalChartArcAngles.leftBottom;
        })

        .attr("data-arcType", "leftInner")
        .style({
            "fill": fill,
            "stroke": stroke,
            "stroke-width": strokeWidth
        });

    leftInnerArc.transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attrTween("d", tweenAttrArc);

function tweenAttrArc(d, i) {
        var arcType = d3.select(this).attr("data-arcType");
        var currentGoal;
        var currentActual;
        var isreversed;

        switch (arcType) {
            case "leftInner":
                currentGoal = d.leftGoal;
                currentActual = d.leftInnerActual;
                isreversed = false;
                break;
            ...
        }
        var previousEndAngle = d3.select(this).attr("endAngle");
        var currentEndAngle = goalChartArcAngles.percent(currentActual, currentGoal, isreversed);

        var interpolator = d3.interpolate(previousEndAngle, currentEndAngle);
        previousEndAngle = currentEndAngle;

        return function (t) {
            return createArc(goalChartArcAngles.leftBottom, interpolator(t), innerArcRadius, innerArcRadius + innerArcWidth)();
        };
    }

function createArc(startAngle, endAngle, innerRadius, outerRadius) {
        return d3.svg.arc()
            .startAngle(startAngle)
            .endAngle(endAngle)
            .innerRadius(innerRadius)
            .outerRadius(outerRadius);
    };
```

When doing a console log in the interpolation function, everything looks fine.

[image: Interpolation Console Log]

But once everything is done, this is what the element looks like.

[image: Element]

What could possibly be causing this?

If I add an 'attr' instead of an 'attrTween', it works just fine.

Comment: The createArc function returns d3.svg.arc function. Invoking the returned function is the difference between assigning the function to the 'd' attribute and the path string. I need the path string.

Comment: I think the problem is that the node I'm assigning in my closure, is not the same node that is being created in the dom. I'm not sure how that is yet, but I'm trying to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having seems to stem from the fact that I was selecting as my base insertion point a div that was also being utilized as a ui-view. I'm not sure exactly why that was causing a problem only for the path element's d attribute, and only for attr tween, but pointing it to a different insertion point fixes the issue.

```
var chart = goalChart(d3.select("div.content"))
```

And the culprit was this

If someone would be able to shed light in the comments about why this is, I would be thankful, but this was such an obscure problem to figure out.